# How can I determine if a vimeo URL is a video? PHP

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-match, vimeo

So I've been using this simple method to determine whether or not a URL is from vimeo

```
if (preg_match("/vimeo/",$url)) {
$getvim = (parse_url($url));
$vimid = str_replace("/", "", $getvim['path']);
}
```

As you can see this simply determines if the url contains "vimeo" then grabs the video id by grabbing everything after the slash. Works fine if you're actually linking a vimeo video, however utterly messes everything up if the link just contains "vimeo" without actually being a vimeo link.

Does anyone have a better method of doing this? There are tons of YouTube solutions available but finding a good vimeo one has been nearly impossible. Any help with this is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$urls = parse_url($url);
if ($urls['host'] == 'vimeo.com'){
    $vimid = ltrim($urls['path'], '/');
    if (is_numeric($vimid)) {
        // do something with $vimid
    }
}
```

We assume that all video IDs are numerical.

Comment: The is_numeric, thank you. I was about to comment about how that's better but I still need to validate whether it's just part of vimeo or an actual video, then I saw you updated it. Perfect solution, thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, I was first thinking you simply need to parse URL, but finally I read the question title :) You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Read the source of the page via `file_get_contents($url)` and then check if it contains the string `<meta property="og:video" content="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=".$vimid." />`  If if contains that string, then you know its a valid video.